# how to run testcontainer with dynamic port for spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch, testcontainers

My test case uses @SpringBootTest annotations to bring up the context and has Autowired some repository. Testcontainer is started in @BeforeAll() method. The problem is RestClientConfig is being initialized/injected before @BeforeAll() in test case. When testcontainer starts, it exports some dynamic port.

I have to set some fixed port in testcontainer 34343 and use the same port in properties file for RestClientConfig.

```
container = new ElasticsearchContainer(ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE)
        .withEnv("discovery.type", "single-node")
        .withExposedPorts(9200)     
        .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostConfig(
                    new HostConfig().withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(34343), new ExposedPort(9200)))));
```

Is there a way to start container and get its dynamic port then use it to initialize RestClientConfig?

I didn't use annoation @Testcontainers though. Is it needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use context configuration initialiser to set properties during runtime, which you can later use in your RestClientConfig.

Let me show you on the example of Postgresql container setup:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Application.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractTestcontainersTest.DockerPostgreDataSourceInitializer.class)
public abstract class AbstractTestcontainersTest {

    protected static final String DB_CONTAINER_NAME = "postgres-auth-test";
    protected static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreDBContainer =
            new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("public.ecr.aws/docker/library/postgres:12.10-alpine")
                    .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres"))
            .withUsername("postgres")
            .withPassword("change_me")
            .withInitScript("db.sql")
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withName(DB_CONTAINER_NAME))
            .withDatabaseName("zpot_main");

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() throws ShellExecutionException {
        postgreDBContainer.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        postgreDBContainer.stop();
    }

    public static class DockerPostgreDataSourceInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    applicationContext,
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreDBContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreDBContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreDBContainer.getPassword()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

All the configuration is done in `DockerPostgreDataSourceInitializer`, where I set all the properties I need. You also need to annotate your test class with `@ContextConfiguration` annotaion. You can do something similar with your ElasticSearchContainer. As I just checked the ElasticSearchContainer has a method `getHttpHostAddress()` which returns host+dynamic_port combination for your container. You can get that host-port pair and set in in properties to be used later in your client configuration. If you need just port you can call `container.getMappedPort(9200)` and again set that port in properties.

2. Regarding @Testcontainers annotation, you need it if you want testcontainers to manage your container lifecycle. In that case you also need to annotate container with @Container annotation. Your container will be started either once before all test methods in a class if your container is a static field or before each test method if it's a regular field. You can read more about that here: https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/#extension.
   Or you can start your container manually either in @BeforeAll or @BeforeEach annotated setup methods. In other words no, you don't have to use `@Testcontainers` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Spring provide `@DynamicPropertySource` for exactly this use case:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html

Your code should look roughly like this:

```java
 @SpringJUnitConfig(...)
 @Testcontainers
 class ExampleIntegrationTests {

     @Container
     static ElasticsearchContainer elastic= new ElasticsearchContainer(ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE)
        .withEnv("discovery.type", "single-node");

     // ...

     @DynamicPropertySource
     static void elasticProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
         registry.add("spring.elasticsearch.uris", elastic::getHttpHostAddress);
     }

 }
```

Comment: for anyone who use this to test elasticsearch: the property should be `spring.elasticsearch.uris` if you use non-deprecated spring data elasticsearch in your properties. `spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris` is deprecated, and these two kinds of properties can't be mixed together, otherwise properties without `rest` will not take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why I used the deprecated key above. I will edit the answer.

Comment: This does not work! It is too early in the lifecycle. Examples RabbitMQ container, Keycloak container. At this point only the JUnit 5 container that manages the container lifecycle has been started. Therefore you will get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started

Comment: You can always call `container.start()` manually.