# Cannot run DB Integration tests with Spring Boot and Testcontainers

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, windows-10, integration-testing

I try to run DB Integration tests with Spring Boot and Testcontainers but without success

I added testcontainer to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the extract of application.properties under test/resources folder

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

.......
logging.file.name=staffaccess-log.log
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=staffaccess
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
debug=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
........
```

Here is  the class where I create a container definition

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {UserRepositoryTCIntegrationTest.Initializer.class})
public class UserRepositoryTCIntegrationTest extends UserRepositoryCommonIntegrationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11.1")
      .withDatabaseName("integration-tests-db")
      .withUsername("sa")
      .withPassword("sa");

    static class Initializer
      implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
              "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
              "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername(),
              "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword()
            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run an integration test, I have the following error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:156)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField.get(FrameworkField.java:92)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.collectAnnotatedFieldValues(TestClass.java:249)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classRules(ParentRunner.java:280)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.withClassRules(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classBlock(ParentRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"Get https://quay.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host"}
```

It seems that there is a problem with docker

I installed docker for windows (I am under windows 10)

as we seem to need a postgres image as the following code suggests

```
@ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11.1")
```

I tried to pull the postgres image, but it gives me an error

```
C:\Users\xflamant>docker pull postgres
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 34.228.211.243:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

here is my host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
10.124.76.38 host.docker.internal
10.124.76.38 gateway.docker.internal

#added to pull postgres image
34.228.211.243 registry-1.docker.io
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Comment: I had similar issue. I am using JUnit5. It works for me now. My test case doesn't extend any other class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976718/how-to-run-testcontainer-with-dynamic-port-for-spring-data-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
in fact I pulled another docker image of Postgres: postgres:13.4-buster. The discussion is closed

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
        "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.4-buster:///databasename?TC_INITSCRIPT=file:src/test/resources/init_script.sql",
        "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver"
})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ApplicationControllerTest  extends InserDataForIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Container
    @Shared
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer  = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:13.4-buster")
            .withDatabaseName("databasename")
            .withUsername("sa")
            .withPassword("sa");;
           

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) throws URISyntaxException {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", () -> "org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver");
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () -> "jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.4-buster:///databasename?TC_INITSCRIPT=file:src/test/resources/init_script.sql");
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
    }





    @BeforeAll
    @Transactional
    public void setup() {
        postgreSQLContainer.start();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password");
        Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        insertData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have succeded in pulling docker image of postgres. The issue was that I had to use a proxy for docker.

However, I have another error

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

 

at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:336)

at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:317)

at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.starting(GenericContainer.java:1066)

at org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:29)

at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)

at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)

at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)

at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)

at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)

at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)

at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception

 at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)

 at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:329)

              ... 12 more

Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
```

My test class is the following

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {ApplicationControllerTest.Initializer.class})

public class ApplicationControllerTest  extends InserDataForIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres")
            .withDatabaseName("staffaccess")
            .withUsername("sa")
            .withPassword("sa");

    static class Initializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword()
            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        postgreSQLContainer.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        postgreSQLContainer.stop();
    }


    @Before
    @Transactional
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password");
        Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        insertData();
    }

    @Test
    public void searchApplicationTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(post("/api/searchApplication")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("appowner", "true")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList("appli")))
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").value(1))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name").value("application1"))
                .andReturn();
    }

    @Test
    public void createApplicationTest() throws Exception {
        int appCount1 = this.applicationRepository.findAllCount();
        int roleCount1 = this.roleRepository.findAllCount();
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(post("/api/createApplication")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new ApplicationDto("application2", Arrays.asList(new RoleDto("role2")), new EnvironmentDto(1, "DEV"), new EmployeeDto(null, null, null, "username"))))
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("application2"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.directorOwner.account").value("username"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.directorOwner.account").value("username"))
                .andReturn();
        int appCount2 = this.applicationRepository.findAllCount();
        int roleCount2 = this.roleRepository.findAllCount();
        Assert.assertEquals(appCount2, appCount1 + 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(roleCount2, roleCount1 + 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllEnvironmentsTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/environments")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name").value("DEV"))
                .andReturn();
    }

    @Test
    public void searchAppNodesTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/searchAppNodes")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("search", "John Doe")
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name").value("DEV"))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

I finally use junit5 and jupiter
For debug facility, i modified my test class as follows

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
@TestPropertySource(ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "application.properties")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ApplicationControllerTest  extends InserDataForIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Container
    @Shared
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:latest")
            .withDatabaseName("staffaccess")
            .withUsername("sa")
            .withPassword("sa");

    static {


        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", postgreSQLContainer.getDriverClassName());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer.getPassword());
    }
```

And I have an error at the line

```
System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl());
```

the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
```

Here is the extract of application.properties

s

```
pring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:latest:///staffaccess
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

### UPDATE2

I have hardcoded the datasource.url

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
@TestPropertySource(ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "application.properties")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ApplicationControllerTest  extends InserDataForIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Container
    @Shared
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:latest")
            .withDatabaseName("staffaccess")
            .withUsername("sa")
            .withPassword("sa");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () -> "jdbc:tc:postgresql:latest:///staffaccess");
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
    }
```

And now, I have the following error (Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$0(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:183)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not create new connection
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.createConnection(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:228)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver.connect(ContainerDatabaseDriver.java:124)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
```